# how to calculate $ p^n + p^{n-1} + \cdots+ p^1 = 300$

Tags: real-analysis, geometric-series

So basically it's been over a decade since i used this stuff and now i could not remember even if my life depended on it...

The challenge is how to calculate $n$ when given the following formula
$1.01^n + 1.01^{n-1} + 1.01^{n-2} + \cdots + 1.01 = 300$
($p$ is a percentage $> 1$ for growth - so in this example it would be a growth of $1\%$ over a period of $n$ until $300$ is reached).

It's enough to point me in the right direction with a keyword I can search for, but if you have time on your hands and feel friendly today pls don't hold back with a full explanation :D

@Mods: Since I have no Idea where to place this Tag-wise feel free to move it where appropriate

Comment: geometric series...

Comment: @Lostcypher Welcome to Math SE. Cf. [Geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: Thank you both : ) Damn you are fast...

Comment: You might also be interested in looking up the future value of an annuity.

Comment: Doug you are smart! That's very close to where i am coming from : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prove that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} p^k = \frac{1-p^{n+1}}{1-p}$ I think you can easily solve in $n$ the following : $\frac{1-p^{n+1}}{1-p} = 300$.

In order to prove the equality $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} p^k = \frac{1-p^{n+1}}{1-p}$ a simple way is to multiply both sides by $(1-p)$ and overlap to sum.

$$(1-p)\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} p^k = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} p^k -p \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} p^k$$

Overlap as follows

$$1 + p + p^2 + p^3 + \cdots + p^n$$

$$\hspace{1.7cm}-p-p^2-p^3-\cdots-p^{n}-p^{n+1}$$

From here you can see that if you sum all the terms cancel out except for the first and the last one, i-e $(1-p)\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} p^k = 1-p^{n+1}$, which leads to what we wanted to prove if you divide for $(1-p)$

Note that I didn't consider the case where $p = 1$ since is a trivial case to consider.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer : ) I can work with this^^